# Ordering by highest price parse

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, pfquery

I have a tableview and I'm trying to access the prices of listings and sort them by the highest price to the lowest price. But when I try, nothing happens. They just load normally. But when I try to order by created at or any other alphabetical string instead of a numerical string it works fine. Can someone provide an edit to my code or a solution to this problem.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
    var query : PFQuery<PFObject>!
    query.order(byDescending: "Price")
     return query
}
```

Comment: Please use proper tags. The [tag:parsing] tag specifically states not to use it for Parse related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery<PFObject> {
    let query = PFQuery<PFObject>()
    query.order(byDescending: "Price")
    return query
}
```

Comment: I did and it didn't work. Sorry I forgot to add copy and paste the return query into the code on this posting. But I already have it in there

Comment: Did you notice the object creating: PFQuery<PFObject>() ?

Comment: look when I do created at instead of price it works. I'm trying to order it by integer. Price is an integer. How can I do that

Comment: I think what works is the default order. It will still work even if you don't do anything. You need to provide more code to help us to find the problem.